# Inject objects into classes that aren't extending ViewModel() Dagger-Hilt

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, dagger-hilt

I have to integrate Dagger Hilt into an exiting application which has all the classes as companion objects.. As an example if we have:

```
class Test {
   companion object {
      // class code
   }
}
```

What is the best approach to convert the code above?
I was thinking to be like this:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class Test @Inject constructor(private val someObject: SomeObject) {
  // class code
}
```

PS: not sure if the @AndroidEntryPoint should be there, as far as I understood with this we have access to component container provided by Hilt